# Как парсить XML CDATA в Go?

Tags: xml, golang

Мне нужно спарить XMl в модель Client, что бы в c.BirthDate.Cdata было 1.01.2000
Как это можно провернуть?
Благодаря `xml:",cdata"` можно записать в XML с CDATA, но обратно не работает.

```
xml := `<client><name>Вася</name><birth_date><![CDATA[1.01.2000]]></birth_date></client>`

type Client struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name   `xml:"client"`
    Name        string     `xml:"name"`
    BirthDate   *BirthDate `xml:"birth_date"`
}
type BirthDate struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"birth_date"`
    Cdata   []byte   `xml:",cdata"`
    Value   []byte   `xml:",chardata"`
}
var c Client
xml.Unmarshal(xml, &c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вам вообще `BirthDate` как отдельный элемент? Вот так же работает:

```
type Client struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"client"`
    Name      string   `xml:"name"`
    BirthDate string   `xml:"birth_date"`
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/P8591sArF2.

Comment: Дело в том, что в документе, с которым я работаю тег CDATA выглядит так : &lt;![CDATA[1.01.2000]]&gt;
Теперь, я понял в чем дело, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

У меня ситуация была такая: стрелки были в виде `&lt; и &gt;` в таком случае Unmarshal неверно работает, не парсит CDATA

```
xmlStr := `<client><name>Вася</name><birth_date>&lt;![CDATA[1.01.2000]]&gt;</birth_date></client>`
```

помогла простая замена

```
b := bytes(xmlStr)
b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte(`&lt;`), []byte("<"), -1)
b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte(`&gt;`), []byte(">"), -1)
```